# why the standard deviation is not as the same as online calculator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, standard-deviation, means

I need to calculate the standard deviation for these numbrs:

```
-12
-3
0
-13
8
-6
0
-22
-1
7
-7
1
-2
-13
-4
0
-6
-4
-10
3
```

I did everything, but still my answer is different from the [online standard deviation calculator](https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/standard-deviation.php), even though i tried many online calculator.

I will state my steps, and please help me to find if there is any mistake:

#### The mean

it is **-4.2**

#### The difference from the mean

```
-7.8
1.2
4.2
-8.8
12.2
-1.8
4.2
-17.8
3.2
11.2
-2.8
5.2
2.2
-8.8
0.2
4.2
-1.8
0.2
-5.8
7.2
```

#### Power the difference from the mean

```
60.84
1.44
17.64
77.44
148.84
3.24
17.64
316.84
10.24
125.44
7.84
27.04
4.84
77.44
0.04
17.64
3.24
0.04
33.64
51.84
```

#### Calculate the variance

56.34

#### Sqrt the variance

7.505997602

it seems that the difference is in the variance,

#### in order to make it easy for your, I uploaded an excel sheet containing the numbers, maybe that is easier for u

[This is the sheet](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F71B93E295302FF2!107&authkey=!AMGXDjlqQCheMg0&ithint=file%2Cxlsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test your sum of square $ s = 60.84 + \dots 51.84$. I get it as $s = 1003.20$. Then depending of the standard deviation type you get for the **sample** std. dev.
$$\sigma_s = \sqrt{s/19} =  7.26636$$ 
or the **population** std. dev.
$$\sigma_p = \sqrt{s/20} = 7.08237$$

Comment: I just found that my self, :) it was my mistake using excel, anyway your answer will be accepted

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to calculate variance. First one is biased estimator and other is unbiased estimator of variance.  In e-gadgets, probably estimator is unbiased estimator and that's what you are getting inconsistent result. Try dividing variance by $n-1$ , the number of data points instead of $n$ and then take square root. Good Luck!

Comment: actually that is not the reason, i just found the reason myself, i was doing the calculation of the variance wrong, i was saying `=SUM(G2,G21)` in excel instead of `=SUM(G2:G21)` and now i have the same value as the website

Comment: just to be consistence: did you say that if you divide on **n** that is called **population std.dev** and if you divide on **n-1** that is called **std.dev** ? (plus one to your efforts)